# How to fight off against a government's internet censorship?

Tags: internet

I live in a country where the left-wing totalitarian regime that it's our government has begun the procedures (legal and physical) to restrict the internet access of it's citizens following the footsteps of China and Cuba. I believe that free access to information is a human right and should not be under any circumstances restricted or sanctioned, i don't want to live in country that does otherwise. Unfortunately leaving for good for the time being it's not an alternative. What I (and all the people that think like me) need to know is; if there are ways of bypassing the possible protections that will be implemented soon?, like the Chinese do . I'm afraid that even proxys might not suffice in the long term since our ISP will be implementing the regulation. Any information or explanation on this will be deeply appreciate it.

Comment: Why are people voting to close? This is entirely related to computers, we're not here to discuss the morality of this one way or another.

Comment: @Phoshi, if it is computer related, then we're talking about Tor, proxies and the like.  All of which have been discussed extensively on SU already.

Comment: @heavyd - then find those and make it a dupe. I agree with Phoshi; this is comp. related. People on this site have some strange moral and organizational issues.

Comment: @heavyd; I have no qualms with closing this as a duplicate, but it's **certainly** not `not computer related`.

Answer (score 6):

The best way that I can think of is to use a SSL VPN. Have a server (a VPS will do) in a country e.g., United States, then set up a SSL connection to the server, and connect to the Internet from there. This assumes that your ISP would not be totally disconnected from other countries.

A cheaper way would be to use Tor service. However, Tor is very slow.

Comment: What do you mean by "This assumes that your ISP would not be totally disconnected from other countries."??

Comment: You can buy VPN/HTTP proxy services directly instead of having to get a VPS and then configure the service yourself.  For less technical users, or those who don't need any other VPS services this is a simpler and less expensive option.

Comment: There is a potential issue with using tor or i2p as another poster responded. That is that since all your traffic is routed through a third party, unless the services you're using on the Internet are encrypted, all your correspondence is in the clear and in the hands of an unknown third party. 

What is to prevent your government from running a tor exit server? 

A VPN really is the best option in my opinion. Although they technically could monitor your traffic they have good business reasons not to.

Comment: @Maxim Z.: there is a probability (a small one) that a leader may just ask all cross-country connections to be disconnected, turning the Internet into a giant Intranet, like how it is in North Korea.

Comment: @ansong yes, someone could setup an outproxy to monitor the traffic that crosses it.  However, all they'd see is possibly the uuid of your i2p node and the IP address of whoever routed your request to the outproxy.  While I'm sure it's technically possible, mapping your UUID to your IP is most likely non-trivial.

Answer (score 5):

[Tor: anonymity online](http://www.torproject.org/)

> Tor is free software and an open
>   network that helps you defend against
>   a form of network surveillance that
>   threatens personal freedom and
>   privacy, confidential business
>   activities and relationships, and
>   state security known as traffic
>   analysis.
>
> Tor protects you by bouncing your
>   communications around a distributed
>   network of relays run by volunteers
>   all around the world: it prevents
>   somebody watching your Internet
>   connection from learning what sites
>   you visit, and it prevents the sites
>   you visit from learning your physical
>   location. Tor works with many of your
>   existing applications, including web
>   browsers, instant messaging clients,
>   remote login, and other applications
>   based on the TCP protocol.
>
> Hundreds of thousands of people around
>   the world use Tor for a wide variety
>   of reasons: journalists and bloggers,
>   human rights workers, law enforcement
>   officers, soldiers, corporations,
>   citizens of repressive regimes, and
>   just ordinary citizens. See the Who
>   Uses Tor? page for examples of typical
>   Tor users. See the overview page for a
>   more detailed explanation of what Tor
>   does, and why this diversity of users
>   is important.

Answer (score 4):

[i2p](http://www.i2p2.de/) is another anonymous proxy system.  It works differently than Tor but it still quite slow.  It essentially creates a virtual encrypted/anonymous network on top of regular IP.  There are web servers that are only accessible via the i2p network.  The i2p network provides things like out proxies and dns proxies that allow you to get to normal (i.e. non i2p) websites.

You need to run an i2p "router" (java software) on your local device to connect to the i2p network.